# Unexpected DeadLock when operating one table

Tags: mysql, deadlock

Recently I meet some unexpected deadlock on product env. The scenario is quite simple:
Assume that we have a table

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    id bigint(20) auto_increment,
    customer_id varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    update_time datetime,
    primary key (id),
    unique key(customer_id)
)
```

assume that I have a record in this table

```
(0, '74597229-fef2-11ea-994a-6c92bf29c398', 'someCustomer', '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

then I have some operation below:

```
start transaction; -- 0
update customer set name = 'deadlockTest' where customer_id = '74597229-fef2-11ea-994a-6c92bf29c398'; -- 1

delete from customer where customer_id = '74597229-fef2-11ea-994a-6c92bf29c398'; --3

commit; -- 5
```

```
update customer set update_time = now() where customer_id in ('74597229-fef2-11ea-994a-6c92bf29c398'); -- 2
```

```
update customer set update_time = now() where customer_id in ('74597229-fef2-11ea-994a-6c92bf29c398'); -- 4
```

the number following '--' means the operation order,

once I execute step 5 (commit), then step 4 will throw a deadlock exception

code block surrounded with '```' means a new thread(or a new window anyway)

- innodb version is 5.6.23

which is really incredible

Comment: i presume step 4 is executed before step 5? How can executing step 5 throw a deadlock exception on modifying a row which does not exists? (because it is deleted in step 3)

Comment: And what's your question here? If your question is why you are getting this deadlock, then you should take a look at innodb status monitor's output on locks.

Comment: BTW what is incredible? the version of mysql? of, more specific, the innodb version of it?  But, seriously, this problem is not reproducable in MySQL version 8.

Comment: My question is why deadlock? the log will be attached later. If interested, u can execute the above statements. Deadlock certainly happened.